# Local notification plugin broken after cordova upgrade

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

I was using [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin for cordova local notification.
Since cordova 5.0.0 with `android@4.0.0` was released it does not work anymore.
I found the bug [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/518).

Is there a way to temporarily solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Quick fix is to modify the block starting at LocalNotification:492 with the following:

webView.getView().post(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      webView.sendJavascript(js);
    } else {
      webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks is works. I just don't understand why the author is not fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

i did a quick solution https://github.com/ivanhuay/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

try `cordova plugin add https://github.com/ivanhuay/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#build_android_solution`

i still have problems in some projects: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION
but it work for me in a new project